# Как установить расширение MonoGame для Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, monogame

Я попытался установить расширение MonoGame на **Visual Studio 2019**, которое добавляет набор шаблонов для создания проектов на MonoGame.

Я зашёл в раздел Extensions > Manage Extensions. В строке поиска ввёл "monogame", но подходящего результата поиска там не было.

Если нет больше никакого способа установить расширение MonoGame на старый VS 2019, скажите, какие ещё есть способы начать проект на фреймворке MonoGame.

Comment: `какие ещё есть способы начать проект` - для ответа на этот вопрос, достаточно зайти на офф сайт и нажать `Getting Started`, тогда вы увидите там раздел установки под [Windows](https://docs.monogame.net/articles/getting_started/1_setting_up_your_development_environment_windows.html), где увидите, что поддержка есть **только** VS 2022, VS Code, а также Rider. Также можете найти это расширение [на сайте](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MonoGame.MonoGame-Templates-VSExtension), где также увидите для какой студии оно.

Comment: Могу кстати ответить на вопрос "почему?". Все дело в том, что нужный вам NuGet пакет для разработки, написан [только для .NET6 и выше](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MonoGame.Framework.DesktopGL#supportedframeworks-body-tab), а .NET6 в свою очередь [не поддерживается](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/compatibility#-visual-studio-2019-support-for-net-development) в 2019 студии. В интернете есть некоторые инструкции как запустить .NET6 в 2019, но вы многое не получите из того, что дает новый .NET, вот и вся суть. Так что, держите всегда свежие IDE под рукой!